# Is this upcasting or downcasting?

Tags: c++, downcast, upcasting

```cpp
int main( )
{
    Base *ptrBase = new Derived( 50, 60, 70 ); 
    Derived *ptrDerived = ( Derived*)ptrBase;
    ptrDerived->printRecord( );
    delete ptrBase;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To plant the picture in your head: Class inheritance hierarchies are usually drawn vertically from the root at top and the inheritance tree's leafs at bottom. So the directions placed before the verb  _casting_ refer to this visualization.

Comment: you cast Derived to Base at first line, then cast from Base to Derive at second line. which you ask?

Comment: since I think it's not unnatured to call derived is build on top of base, I would prevent use `up` and `down` myself. Simply call it *cast to base* or *case to xxx* is better imho.

Answer (score 2):

Upcast is from derived to base, downcast from base to derived. So in your case it is a downcast.

Comment: @prajwalrajodiya You are welcome. If this answers your question, you can accept it as an answer.